# Error message while using BigQuery: Unrecognized name: HTN_Global

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm getting `Unrecognized name: HTN_Global` whenever I try to run the following query.  What can I do to make it right? **HTN_Global** is the name of my dataset.

```
SELECT
  COALESCE(hospital_ID,
    name) AS hypertension_case,
  gender,
  age,
  district,
  sector,
  facility,
  month,
  year
FROM
  HTN_Global.emr_data
FULL OUTER JOIN
  HTN_Global.log_data_sorted
ON
  HTN_Global.emr_data.names = HTN_Global.log_data_sorted.names
```

Comment: Guess you forgot to attach "the above error message" for people to see.

Answer (score 0):

I used to have this type of problem when I was logged into project-a and was querying project-b. All errors I usually avoided using the full format: `` FROM `project-a.dataset_name.table_name` AS table_alias ``. With this full format, the only error I could get is to not have access to project-a.

Also I got this error when moving from legacy-sql to standard-sql. A good practice is to put in the begging of the query `#standardSQL` so bigquery understands that query as a query that follows the Standard SQL code.